# UFW appears to ignore rules

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch

I installed ufw on my raspberry pi 2 which is running Raspbian Stretch. After starting ufw I set a rule, `sudo ufw allow from 8.8.8.8`. I then denied both incoming and outgoing with `sudo ufw default deny incoming` and `sudo ufw default deny outgoing`. However, when I try to ping 8.8.8.8, it states that the operation is not permitted. How do I allow my raspberry pi to connect?